# How to delete n-th element of array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

For example I have this document:

```
db.test.save({
  _id: 1,
  list: [
    { key: "a" },
    { key: "b" },
    { key: "c" },
    { key: "d" },
    { key: "e" }
  ]
})
```

and I need remove to the second element from the list.

For now I do that in two steps. I first unset the second list element but the `$unset` operator doesn't remove the element, it modifies it to `null`, and after that I pull any nullable value from the list field:

```
db.test.update({_id: 1}, {$unset: {"list.2": 1}})
db.test.update({_id: 1}, {$pull: {list: null}})
```

Is there a solution to do that in one operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, unfortunately what you are doing is currently the best option. Have a look at this question: [In mongoDb, how do you remove an array element by its index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4588303/586748) which links to a Jira for this very issue.

Answer (score 3):

if you know the value which you want to remove

```
db.test.update({{_id: 1},{"$pull" : {"list" : { "key" : "c"}}},false,false)
```

more info at

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ValueinanArray

Comment: Is it possible to use this with `findAndModify` where the id of the document and the existence of the array item are used as the query arguments?

Comment: Why you use ¿"false,false"? Thank you! very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Starting in `Mongo 4.4`, the [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) aggregation operator allows applying a custom javascript function to implement behaviour not supported by the MongoDB Query Language.

For instance, in order to update an array by removing an element at a given index:

```
// {
//   "_id" : 1,
//   "list" : [
//     { "key" : "a" },
//     { "key" : "b" },
//     { "key" : "c" },
//     { "key" : "d" },
//     { "key" : "e" }
//   ]
// }
db.collection.aggregate(
  { $set:
    { "list":
      { $function: {
          body: function(list) { list.splice(2, 1); return list; },
          args: ["$list"],
          lang: "js"
      }}
    }
  }
)
// {
//   "_id" : 1,
//   "list" : [
//     { "key" : "a" },
//     { "key" : "b" },
//     { "key" : "d" },
//     { "key" : "e" }
//   ]
// }
```

`$function` takes 3 parameters:

- `body`, which is the function to apply, whose parameter is the array to modify. The function here simply consists in using splice to remove 1 element at index 2.
- `args`, which contains the fields from the record that the `body` function takes as parameter. In our case `"$list"`.
- `lang`, which is the language in which the `body` function is written. Only `js` is currently available.

Answer (score -1):

Not at the current time. As it was answered in [There is no straight way of pulling/removing by array index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4588909/3051783).

There is an open issue asking for that operation, even though this workaround is ok, notwithstanding it is not an atomic solution.