# How to atomically pop random element?

Tags: mongodb, random, atomic

Is there a way to atomically pop (remove and retrieve) a random element with MongoDB - like Redis's [SPOP](http://redis.io/commands/spop)?

I've read the [RandomAttribute tutorial](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/random-attribute/) but now I need to make sure that the element is also removed when fetched, and this must be done atomically.

I guess as an alternative I could push the data into an array field pre-sorted, but I'd really prefer to have it fetch a random record.

Looking at `$pop`'s documentation, it seems it can't take arguments, so it either removes the first or the last element of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updates within collections in Mongo are atomic, so combining `findAndModify` with the RandomAttribute approach will do the trick:

```
var rand = Math.rand();
db.collection.findAndModify({query: {random: {$gte: rand}}, remove: true});
```

Just make sure to also query for `random: {$lt: rand}` when the above returns `null`.

Protip: some drivers have `findAndRemove`, which is the same as `findAndModify` with `remove: true`.

Answer (score 0):

There basically isn't currently a nice way to do what you want to do. The big problem is that there isn't an atomic way to delete an element of an array by its position.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227890/how-to-delete-n-th-element-of-array-in-mongodb/7228140#7228140) for more info on this.

The best - nearest to atomic - way I can think of to work around this is the following. It relies on you being able to handle null elements in the array for a short time (this is the bit that isn't atomic).

**Step One**

Generate a random number on the client side. Use this to specify the key of the array element you want to remove in dot notation (ie. "my_array.4") as AFAIK this can't be done dynamically in the query.

**Step Two**

Use the random number to atomically unset the selected element of the array while retrieving it as it was *before* the update using `findAndModify` with `new` set to false. Assuming the random number you generated was `4`, you'd do something like the following:

```
db.mycollection.findAndModify({
  query: {_id: 1},
  update: {$unset: {"my_array.4" : true }},
  fields: {my_array : {$slice : [4, 1]}, _id : false},
  new: false
});
```

(NB. `findAndModify` currently returns the document pre-update by default, but I read somewhere that that might change, so it's a good idea always to specify which you want using the `new` option.)

This will leave the array element that was selected as a `null` value in the array.

**Step Three**

Remove the null element from the array with another update, using $pull:

```
db.mycollection.update({_id: 1}, {$pull: {my_array: null}})
```

Phew! Seems like a lot of work for what you want to do. I don't know Redis but SPOP sounds a lot easier. I hope this helps a bit though, anyway. It's not a single atomic operation, but (as long as you can handle those nulls) I think the most important parts of it are. You're never going to get into a situation where two different threads pop the same element at nearly the same time, which, I'm guessing, is what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: I've stumbled into findAndModify meanwhile and I'm using it combined with the RandomAttribute approach. It's something like db.items.findAndModify({query: {random: {$gte: rand}}, remove: true}).