# Pull item by value from embedded array in Mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I want to pull a specific item from an embedded array...assume the following mongo document....

`db.test.find()`

```
{
  id:1,
  comments : 
   [
     { cid: 1 },
     { cid: 2 },
     { cid: 3 },
     { cid: 4 },
     { cid: 5 }
   ]
}
```

I want to remove an item from the `comments` array by `cid`, not by position. I've tried all of these but none of them appear to work. I've tried using the dot notation, but that does not seem to have any effect. I tried the last post suggestion from [How to Delete-nth element from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227890/how-to-delete-n-th-element-of-array-in-mongodb), but no luck...

```
db.test.update({ 'comments.cid' : 5}, {"$pull" :{"comments":{"cid":"3"}}}    )
db.test.update(  {id: 1}, {"$pull" : {"comments" : { "cid" : "3"}}},false,false)
db.test.update(  {id: 1}, {"$pull" :{"comments.cid" :3}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These worked too...

```
db.test.update({comments:{cid:4} }, 
                    {$pull:{comments:{cid:4}},  
                      $inc:{commentCount: -1}})

db.test.update({"comments.cid" : 17}, 
                     {$pull:{ comments:{cid: 17}}, 
                      $inc:{commentCount:-1}})
```

Comment: How to pass Array of condition like ```db.test.update({"comments.cid" : 17}, 
                     {$pull:{ comments: {$in: [{cid: 17}, {cid: 18}]}, 
                      $inc:{commentCount:-1}})``` isn't working.

Answer (score 12):

this should work:

```
db.test.update(  {id: 1}, {$pull :{comments: {cid :3}}})
```

also, in your document, you have:
id: 1 without comma at the end, it shold be:

```
id:1,
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you...is it possible to take this one step further using `findAndModify` where I want to remove the array item only if the document exists, and, the array item exists? In other words, `findAndModify( query:{id:1, $where "comments.cid = 3"}, ...`

Comment: I think that with the query you already have it will remove it only if document with id 1 exists and comment with cid exists...how it would remove it anyway? :) or did I get you wrong?

Comment: yes, you're right, but in my document, I also have a `commentsCounter`, I did not mention this at first, it keeps track of the number of items in the `comments` array, so when I use `findAndModify`, I want to remove the item from the array and decrement `commentsCounter` only if the item exists, but if it does not, make no changes to the document at all, not the array or the counter

Comment: got it..not sure how that can be done though...perhaps you will have to use http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution for that purpose...not sure if findAndModify will help.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/45725/vucetica I'll use you original suggestion and answer as a starting point, thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2):

Just wanted to modify the answer so that it can delete multiple objects from an array.

```
db.test.update(  {id: 1}, {"$pullAll" : {"comments" : [{ "cid" : "3"},{ "cid" : "2"}]}})
```

This answer has been updated and it works with mongoose too