# Mongo remove array index

Tags: mongodb

I am trying delete a specific index from the questions array. I have followed the examples in these two posts:

[In mongoDb, how do you remove an array element by its index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588303/in-mongodb-how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-by-its-index)

[How to delete n-th element of array in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227890/how-to-delete-n-th-element-of-array-in-mongodb)

```
 var quiz =  {
                        quizName: "",
                        createdBy: "",
                        theme: "",
                        isPrivate: "",
                        expiringDate: "",
                        createdOn: "",
                        questions:[
                                   {question: "",
                                   index: "",
                                   answers: [
                                             answer: "",
                                             radioCorrect: "",
                                             index: ""
                                   ]},{
                                   question: "",
                                   index: "",
                                   answers: [
                                             answer: "",
                                             radioCorrect: "",
                                             index: ""
                                   ]}

                        ]
```

This is giving me a not specified error. I have tried similar variations of this.

```
'deleteQuiz': function(quizId, index1){ 


    Quizes.update({_id: quizId},{ $unset : {questions.index1: 1}})

    Quizes.update({_id: quizId},{ "$pull" : {"questions": null}}) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the update object prior to using in your update operation. You can use the [square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to create it as follows:

```
'deleteQuiz': function(quizId, index1){ 
    var query = {"_id": quizId},
        update { "$unset": { } };

    update["$unset"]["questions."+index1] = 1;
    Quizes.update(query, update)

    /* or if using the $pull operator
    var query = {"_id": quizId},
        update = { "$pull": { } };

    update["$pull"]["questions."+index1] = null;
    Quizes.update(query, update)    
    */
}
```

Comment: Thank you chridam, it worked like charm! I just had to put a = sign after update.

Comment: @SpiritCode No worries, happy to help :) Left out the `=` as a typo, its been corrected now.