# pymongo: searching and editing fields within document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, database

Say i have this database "list", which contains a collection called "users", which contain, among others, an object called "david"

> {u'_id': u'david', u'url': u'url3', u'old_url': u'url3', u'wishlist': [[u'Jenara', u'shards', u'nm'], [u'force of will', u'mm2', u'nm'], [u'pact of negation', u'mm', u'nm'], [u'all is dust', u'mm4', u'nm']]}

how can i use pymongo to edit the arrays within the wishlist field? say i want to remove one of the four arrays, or edit one of them?

Answer (score 1):

In order to update an element in an array, use [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/). Here is an example - updating the second element and setting it's value to `["something", "else"]`:

```
db.users.update({'_id': 'david'}, {"$set": {"wishlist.1": ["something", "else"]}})
```

As for the removing an item from an array by index, it's not that easy and straightforward, see:

- [In mongoDb, how do you remove an array element by its index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588303/in-mongodb-how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-by-its-index)
- [How to delete n-th element of array in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227890/how-to-delete-n-th-element-of-array-in-mongodb?lq=1)

Comment: in this case you know the index (1) of the item you want to edit. what if you don't? says you want to edit the item that starts with "[Jenara,"

Comment: and how can i delete an entry?