# Mongo DB make an array with date as key?

Tags: php, mongodb

Mongo make an array with date as key ?

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 4fcf2f2313cfcd225700000d
)
[id] => 14
[name] => Aryan Roban
[news] => Array (
    [08-06-2012] => 12
)
```

Here I want a make news as array with date as key and how to delete a particular key row ?

For example

I want to delete array element with key '08-06-2012' in news array , I dont know the value of it.

Comment: Isn't the date rather a string? And here is a possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588303/in-mongodb-how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-by-its-index

Comment: date itself.. either date('d-m-Y') or date('Y-m-d')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding Documents won't be a problem, this is very easy. Simply look if `news` has got a key which matches your search criteria:

```
db.foo.find({'news.08-06-2012': {'$exists': true}})
```

Don't forget to put an index on `news`.

But deleting them is not easily possible. There is another thread which show shows a way to do that, but it's really rather a workaround: [In mongoDb, how do you remove an array element by its index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588303/in-mongodb-how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-by-its-index) Sadly this only works for arrays with numerical indexes and not for associative arrays.

Maybe you could use an own collection for news? Then you could update and delete them easily. Otherwise you could load a full document from your database, manipulate the news in your application and save it afterwards. This would require two datebase queries, but should work.

Comment: Is it possible to make  array `news.08-06-2012` today, tommorrow I want to add  `news.09-06-2012` into same news array. i.e updating the news array every day, but without resetting  whole news array... I used the `$set` but it is resetting whole news array

Comment: Adding a news is possible using `$set`: `db.foo.update({/*...*/}, {$set: {'news.09-06-2012', 'whatever'}})` (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set) But you cannot easily delete items that way.

Comment: If `db.foo.update({/*...*/}, {$inc: {'news.11-06-2012', 1}})`, whether news array will create an new array element as count ?   i.e `[11-06-2012] => 1` to existing array

Comment: `db.foo.update({/*...*/}, {$unset: {'news.11-06-2012', 1}})` has worked great ...

Comment: Awesome! At the end this looks great. :-)

Answer (score 0):

We can use like

```
db.foo.update({/*...*/}, {$unset: {'news.11-06-2012', 1}})
```