# How to create a query for embedded object in Mongo?

Tags: java, mongodb

Any one help me to create mongo query for deleting where "name" : "gdfgdfgdfg" embedded document

The object stored as below in Mongo db.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("50656f33a4e82d3f98291eff"),
    "description": "gdfgdfgdfg",
    "menus": [
    {
        "name": "gdfgdfgdfg"**,
        "description": "dfgdgd",
        "text": "dfgdfg",
        "key": "2",
        "onSelect": "yyy",
        "_id": ObjectId("50656f3ca4e82d3f98291f00")
    },
    {
        "name": "dfg",
        "description": "dfgdfgdfgdf",
        "text": "dfgdgf",
        "key": "1",
        "onSelect": "uuuu",
        "_id": ObjectId("50656f44a4e82d3f98291f01")
    }
    ]
}
```

Any one help me, I'm new to Mongo

Comment: thanks for editing, i m new to stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JavaScript shell you can do this:

```
var query = {"_id": ObjectId("50656f33a4e82d3f98291eff")};
db.collection.update(query, {'$pull':{ menus: {name : 'gdfgdfgdfg'} } });
```

or use the Id.

```
db.collection.update(query, {'$pull': { menus: {"_id": ObjectId("50656f3ca4e82d3f98291f00")} } });
```

With the Java Driver should be something like this:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId("50656f33a4e82d3f98291eff"));

BasicDBObject docToRemove = new BasicDBObject("name", "gdfgdfgdfg");

BasicDBObject updateCommand = new BasicDBObject("$pull", new BasicDBObject("menus", docToRemove));

collection.update(query, updateCommand);
```

Comment: how to update i have tried like this BasicDBObject updateCommand = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("menus", docToRemove));

Comment: the update() function is from the collection. `DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("test"); collection.update(query, updateCommand);`

Answer (score 0):

Mongo won't let you delete the embedded document. What you have to do is take the object from the collection, delete the one object in the list, and then save it back into the database.

```
obj = db.collection.findOne({"_id": ObjectId("50656f33a4e82d3f98291eff")});
menus = obj.menus.splice(0,1); // Or some other way to manually delete
                               // the one item in the list
db.collection.update({"_id": ObjectId("50656f33a4e82d3f98291eff")},
                     {$set: {menus: menus}});
```

It's complicated, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588303/in-mongodb-how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-by-its-index).

**EDIT**: If you don't know the index, you can try this:

```
obj = db.collection.findOne({"_id": ObjectId("50656f33a4e82d3f98291eff")});
var i = 0;
for(i=0;i<obj.menus.length;i++) {
    if(obj.menus[i].name === "gdfgdfgdfg")
        break;
}
menus = obj.menus.splice(i,1);
db.collection.update({"_id": ObjectId("50656f33a4e82d3f98291eff")},
                     {$set: {menus: menus}});
```

Comment: thanks. it helps me,is it possible to delete the document without splicing using the  "_id": ObjectId("50656f3ca4e82d3f98291f00").it need some thing concrete

Comment: I have tried this below code but its deleting whole document WriteResult result = db.collection.remove(new BasicDBObject("_id", ObjectId("50656f33a4e82d3f98291eff")), WriteConcern.NORMAL));

Comment: In mongodb, embedded documents are *not* treated the same way as collection documents. There is no query to delete single array members. You have to do it manually.

Answer (score -1):

```
$conditionArray=array("_id"=>ObjectId("50656f33a4e82d3f98291eff"));
$dataArray=array("description"=>"");
$db->$collectionName->update($conditionArray,array('$unset' =>$dataArray))->limit(1);
```

Comment: thanks, But i want to delete only the first document {
        "name": "gdfgdfgdfg"**,
        "description": "dfgdgd",
        "text": "dfgdfg",
        "key": "2",
        "onSelect": "yyy",
        "_id": ObjectId("50656f3ca4e82d3f98291f00")
    }  in the menus.

Comment: This is nonsense. It only deletes the description field.