# Deleting object from an array in collections [performance / best practice / issues]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So I have a Collection named Pages, and inside of this collection, each page has an array of Widgets, each widget has an uuid which I use to identify each widget.

```
Pages [ 
     widgets : [{uuid : "someuuid"}, {uuid : "otheruuid"}]
]
```

I need to remove an item from a `widgets` array and update the collection. So I read in this post [about how to remove items in an array (Mongo DB approach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588303/in-mongodb-how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-by-its-index).
Example of the post:

```
db.people.update({"name":"dannie"}, {'$pull': {"interests": "guitar"}})
```

I tried it, but it didn't work for my project, Dont know why, I am not sure why, I don't know how to write the mongodb instructions

So since I have to keep working I did something like this:

```
//random function to get index of an object in the array;
var indexOf = myfunction.getIndexOfObject()
if (indexOf > -1) {
    //remove the item in the array of the Active Page
    activePage.widgets.splice(indexOf, 1);
    //update the collection
    Pages.update({_id : activePage._id},activePage); 
}
```

I would like to know if my approach is correct; it works fine without any problems. But I dont know if could have any issue or caveat in performance or security or whatever other thing, since the documentation approach is totally different:

Documentation approach:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

```
db.cpuinfo.update(
                   { flags: "msr" },
                   { $pull: { flags: "msr" } },
                   { multi: true }
                 )
```

thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although whatever you are doing seems to be correct but I tired using $pull for updating array I could do it.
I created a sample page collections and inserted following docs

```
db.pages.insert({widgets : [{uuid : "someuuid1"}, {uuid : "otheruuid2"}]});
db.pages.insert({widgets : [{uuid : "someuuid2"}, {uuid : "otheruuid3"}]});
db.pages.insert({widgets : [{uuid : "someuuid3"}, {uuid : "otheruuid3"}]});
db.pages.insert({widgets : [{uuid : "someuuid3"}, {uuid : "otheruuid4"}]});
```

The I ran update query to pull elements

```
db.pages.update({},{$pull : {"widgets" : {uuid : "otheruuid3"}}}, {multi:true});
```

I can see document 2 and 3 do not have "uuid : otheruuid3" in widgets. Not really sure what issue you are facing

Comment: Ohh actually I never used the multi:true thats new for me.. what do that property?

Comment: {multi:true} is the expression for updating all documents matching the criterion by default it is false and in that case only one document is updated.  See the link below                  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter/#multi-parameter