# Removing null values from array object mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How can I remove null elements from this array with updateMany? I have many documents following this pattern with null values and I want to update them all without null values.

```
{

  "car": "Honda",
  "color": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    "red",
    "orange"

    
  ]
}
```

I tried

```
db.db_urls.updateMany({color: null}, { $unset : { color: 1 }})
```

but it is removing the contents of all fields

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing null objects from json in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497382/removing-null-objects-from-json-in-mongodb)

Comment: `update({},{"$pull": {"color": {"$eq": null}}},{"multi": true})` try this if you are still stuck, i think you need this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**: using aggregation pipeline inside update() query with `$filter`

```
db.collection.update({
 color: {
  $exists: true,
  $eq: null
 }
},
[
 {
  $addFields: {
   color: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$color",
      as: "c",
      cond: {
        $ne: [
          "$$c",
          null
        ]
      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
],
{
 multi: true
})
```

Explanation:

1. Match only documents where array color exist and contain at least single null value
2. Replace the color array with same with no null values
3. Add {multi:true} to apply to all found documents

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aChtxaUoTrH)

**Option 2**: remove all null elements in color array with `$pull`

```
db.collection.update({
 color: {
   $exists: true,
   $eq: null
 }
},
{
 $pull: {
   color: null
}
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

Explanation:

1. Match all documents having color array and at least single null element.
2. Remove (`$pull`) all null color  array elements
3. Apply to all matched documents (`multi:true`)

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BnmW2I54Y39)

I would use the option 2 since it looks simple, but in certain cases for bigger collections, the `$pull` operation may perform slower so is better to test ...