# MongoDb $pull by array index

Tags: mongodb

I was looking to pull(remove) values from my data collection based on array index.
this is how my collection looks.

```
"experience" : [ 
        "neeee", 
        "avvvvvvv", 
    ],
```

I'm looking to remove `experience[1]`

```
 var update = {
    $pull: {
      'profile.experience': delet
    }
  };
 this.findByIdAndUpdate(id,update,{ 'new': true},function(err,doc) {
    if (err) { console.log(err);
      callback(err);
    } else if(doc){
      callback(null,doc);
    }
```

my `delet` looks like this: `[1]`
i was not able to delete (pull) what may be the reason.

Comment: try this => var myObj = ...; collection.findOneAndUpdate(  {uniqueAttr: myObj.uniqueAttr}, myObj,{upsert: true}, function(...) {...});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In mongoDb, how do you remove an array element by its index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588303/in-mongodb-how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-by-its-index)