# MongoDB: remove array element by index, order of operations?

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to figure out if mongo can remove an array element by index:

[In mongoDb, how do you remove an array element by its index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588303/in-mongodb-how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-by-its-index)

The top answer mentions a workaround:

```
db.lists.update({}, {$unset : {"interests.3" : 1 }}) 
db.lists.update({}, {$pull : {"interests" : null}})
```

This got me wondering, if one were to combine these two commands, would mongo execute them in order? For example:

```
db.lists.update({}, {
  $unset : {"interests.3" : 1 }, 
  $pull : {"interests" : null}
})
```

Would mongo execute in order the $unset first, and then the $pull?

Comment: I get an error when I try it: "Updating the path 'interests' would create a conflict at 'interests'"

Comment: Ah, I probably should have just tested it myself haha. Thanks for letting me know! :)