# Deleting a field with $unset operation it just converting it to a null value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to delete some fields on my mongodb database but instead the fields are just getting mutated to a null value and that's an issue because when fetching data im using loops and they get broken passing true `null` value ... for deleting data i'm using the following :

```js
 User.updateOne({_id : user._id } ,{ $unset :{ "days.0.tasks.0" = "" })
```

what i'm getting :

[image]

Is there a way to delete entirely the objects inside the tasks array?

Comment: is `tasks` an array?

Comment: @FelDev as you can see on the picture yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$unset is not working as you'd expect it because you are using it on an element inside an array. Removing the element at position 0 means shifting all other elements in the array. To prevent messing with those other elements, $unset is setting the element at position 0 to null.

[MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/update/pop/#definition)

I suggest using the $pull operator to delete specific elements from an array or use $pop for the first / last items .

**OR :**

you can get the user tasks array and splice it then push it back using `$set` operator.

Comment: Thank you but $pop removes only the first or last element of an array i need to delete a specific item on the array

Comment: How about $pull then?

Comment: $pull requires you to specify a condition, though.

Comment: Else I think you'll find what you're looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588303/in-mongodb-how-do-you-remove-an-array-element-by-its-index

Comment: hey i actually figured out a way from the answer that you mentioned and some personal efforts ...i will edit your answer so i can accept it